# Javascript rename file on download

Tags: javascript, file, download

I want to be able to download a web file, but when the download dialog open, the filename is renamed.

Ex: File: `http://<server>/<site>/test.txt`

and when I click to download the file, download dialog open with the file name: `test001.txt`.

How can I achive that?

Answer (score 23):

As InviS suggests, now there's a `download` attribute on links.

Example:

```
<a href="http://server/site/test.txt" download="test001.txt">Download Your File</a>
```

- [spec](http://developers.whatwg.org/links.html#downloading-resources)
- [article](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download)
- [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) (Chrome, FF, Opera, Android Browser >= 4.4.4 at the time of writing)

Comment: I use this in combination with target="_blank" for other browsers.

Comment: Any way to append the current user's date to the filename? I only found how to change the `<a>` content (like "click her to download"), but not the value inside `download="value"`

Comment: @DaniSpringer you can try dynamically setting the attribute via the `onclick` handler, but there may be limitations

Comment: @DmitryPashkevich thanks for your response. I asked today and got a pretty good answer. You can find the question via my account. I'm sure you know your way around SO. ;) if you think it is well asked, please up vote.

Answer (score 13):

You can used the download attribute on a link tag `<a href="http://server/site/test.txt" download="test001.txt">Download Your File</a>`

However, when content-disposition header is set on the server response, it will ignore the download attribute and the filename will be set to the filename in the content-disposition response header

You can accomplish this using axios, or any other fetch by doing this:

```
const downloadAs = (url, name) => {
  Axios.get(url, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
    },
    responseType: "blob"
  })
    .then(response => {
      const a = document.createElement("a");
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
      a.href = url;
      a.download = name;
      a.click();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("error", err);
    });
};
```

usage:

```
downloadAs('filedownloadlink', 'newfilename');
```

Note: if your file is large, it will look like it is not doing anything until the whole file has been downloaded, so make sure you show some message or some indication to the user to let them know it is doing something

Answer (score 2):

This effect is accomplished by sending an additional header. You can use PHP, for example, to achieve this:

URLs can be rewritten using `.htaccess`, (internally) redirecting the request to a PHP file. I will show a simple hard-coded example, of how the header can be set:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/plain');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test001.txt"');
    readfile('files/test.txt');
     //assuming that the files are stored in a directory, not in a database
?>
```

Comment: but this does not acomplish the dynamic nature he is looking for. My guess of course

Comment: I showed how the headers can be set. If he has the skills to program in PHP, he can alter the code to accomplish his goal.

Answer (score 2):

Use `download` attribute of the link. But it works only in Chrome browser :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in Javascript. The "Save to"-dialog is openend by the browser and you can't access that through JS, it's a standard-dialog from the OS.

Your server must provide the file with the desired name before the user clicks on the download-link.

What's the reason that you want to rename the downloaded file anyway?

Comment: I have the files in a Sharepoint library and I'm trying to create a custom action to download the files and add the document version in the file name. 
To do this custom action I can only use javascript code. 

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to return a continuous type of file name, you have to write a script that will keep track of that and provide that file back to the user. One way is using plain PHP, or something more advanced if it is several files at a time, possibly a cURL call in php so it can generate several different files. I am guessing that is what you are looking on doing, but you can't have the file name changed dynamically on the save box in that sense, you return the savename.txt filename.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the file using **Fetch API**, convert the fetch response into a **Blob**, create a blob URL from the blob, and then use an anchor with the download attribute (using the desired name) to download the file from the blob URL.

```
        <Link
            onClick={async() => {
                const url = `https://external-website.com/${file.s3Key}`;
                const downloadedFile = await fetch(url).then(response => {
                    if (response.ok) {
                        return response.blob();
                    }
                    else {
                        errorToast('It was not possible to download the file');
                        return undefined;
                    }
                });
                if (downloadedFile) {
                    const a = document.createElement('a');
                    const downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(downloadedFile as any);
                    a.href = downloadUrl;
                    a.download = file.filename; // use the name you want
                    a.click();
                }
            }}
            sx={{
                textDecoration: 'none',
                fontSize: 16,
                cursor: 'pointer'
            }}
        >
            Download
        </Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use fetch API you can do it like so:

```
const downloadFile = async (url, fileName) => {
  const response = await fetch(url, { method: "GET" });
  const blob = await response.blob();
  const urlDownload = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const link = document.createElement("a");

  link.href = urlDownload;
  link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
  link.click();
};

// usage
downloadFile('../myFile.zip', 'whatever.zip')
```