# Rename download file using a redirect

Tags: javascript

I am currently downloading a file via an S3 pre-signed url like so:

```
window.location.href = result.data.downloadUrl;
```

the only thing I can find to do such a thing is this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56195387/904278

but I don't love the approach of clicking programatically.

Is there a better way?

Comment: drive by downloads are discouraged.

Comment: This is for an internal tool. When you click a download button, the pre-signed url is generated and `window.location.href = result.data.downloadUrl;` is ran. So it's not really a surprise to the user they're getting a download. However, this has made me think of a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do.