# Is there a way to rename files on download from an <a> href?

Tags: javascript, html, url

My website is called [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), and I keep my files in a storage bucket called storage.example.com.

Each file has a hash-like filename in the bucket (to prevent scrapers), but I would like to rename this to something sensible when a user clicks the download link from [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

In the old days, you used to be able to use the `download` attribute within `<a>`, however, the MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) say that this only works for same-origin URLs, and storage.example.com is considered to be [different](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#definition_of_an_origin). This means that `download` attribute is ignored, and the default hash-like filename is used.

Is there an easy way to do this in 2022? Many answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428831/javascript-rename-file-on-download) are written before modern browsers started blocking the desired behavior. I understand that it seems like I am trying to bypass a security feature, so I am also open to suggestions that achieve the same outcome while not compromising security.

Note: the files are small zip files (~30kB), so a solution that downloads, renames then presents the result to the user would work.

Comment: The only way that I'm aware of to successfully do this cross-domain would be to have `storage.example.com` send an appropriate `Content-Disposition` header in its response to the resulting request, a la `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg"`.

Comment: "*Each file has a hash-like filename in the bucket (to prevent scrapers)*" Are these publicly-accessible files, or are they supposed to only be accessed by specific users? If the former - why do you care about scrapers? For the latter - sounds like you're missing a critical piece of an authorization flow here - what you have proposed is not particularly effective security.

Comment: @esqew Yes these are publicly accessible files, but the link is served via an authenticated API. The reason the filename is a hash is to make it difficult to do a bulk scrape of these files directly from the storage bucket

Comment: Could you fetch() the file into a blob and then create a local url for download? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25547475/save-to-local-file-from-blob https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/create-and-save-a-file-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

The option suggested by esqew in the comments above seems to be the best solution for my problem. If the files are kept in a Google Storage Bucket, you can edit the metadata of a blob and set the Content-Disposition field:

[image]

This adds an additional step when new files are added but I automated this using a [Python script](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#storage-set-object-metadata-python)

I also tried This Guy's suggestion by saving to a blob using FileSaver.js, however it has the undesired effect of setting off the pop-up blocker in the current version of Chrome